# Referencing DOM elements in dynamic table created with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that is dynamically generated. Each row contains a `select` (aka drop down menu)  and a `checkbox`.

On change of the `select`, I want to additionally change properties for the `checkbox`, however I am unsure how to reference the `checkbox` from a `ng-change` function.

Here is a dynamic HTML table:

```
</table>  
 <tr ng-repeat = "(index, item) in items">
    <td >
        <select ng-model="item.myDropDown" ng-change="dropDownChange()">
             <option value="A"> A </option>
             <option value="B"> B </option>
        </select>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.myCheckbox" value="unchecked" disabled='disabled'/>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now I try to reference these elements on change using:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) { 
        $scope.dropdownChange = function() {
            console.debug(this.item.toDoDropdown); //I am able to reference the select-option values
            document.getElementById(this.item.myCheckbox).checked = true; //This is placeholder code to signify my intent at referencing the checkbox
        }
}
```

It appears to me that the `checkbox` is not in the `scope` for this `ngChange` function, however I am unsure how to rectify this.
Additionally, I attempted to give each table row its own controller as recommended on my internet travels, namingly [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2450-using-ngcontroller-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm); is this indeed good practice?

Comment: maybe im missing something, but `document.getElemntById(this.item.myCheckBox)` shouldn't return the element, it has no id attribute and the value `this.item.myCheckBox` isn't an id selector

Comment: You are entirely correct. I have used this as a placeholder, to show my intent at accessing the checkbox. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the index and item to the method: `dropDownChange($index,item)`

```
$scope.dropdownChange = function($index,item){
    item.myCheckbox = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. Is there a reason why the scope of the function is different to that of $index and item? I was under the impression that the function could reference this data already.

Comment: Additionally, it appears that only true/false can be set in this manner - I am unable to disable/enable the checkboxes

Comment: I think what you have on your scope is actually items, not the iteration variable item.